# Is it legal to use the cardinality of a universal quantifier in relational calculus?

Tags: predicate-logic, relation-algebra

For example, if I wanted to make a set of all $x$'s that satisfied some predicate function $f(x, y)$ with exactly 2 different values of $y$, is this a legal statement:

$\{x |\ |(\forall y)(f(x, y))|=2 \}$

Comment: You have to check the list of [Set operations in Relational algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Set_operators).

Comment: In predicate logic, you cannot do it that way: there are no set operations.